# Is there a way in MacOS to view filesystem details, including cluster size, for an already created exFAT partition?

Tags: macos, filesystem, exfat

I am interested in viewing the existing cluster size (aka allocation unit) and other FS details for an already created exFAT partition.  My attempts in searching, including here, have only led to answers about how to choose and specify what the cluster size ***will be*** for a newly formatted disk.  That has already been done, and I now want to view what ***was*** done.

I'd like to use anything available on my Mac, that is, not have to use any external software, including Windows.  If there's a command that shows this, all the better.

Thank you for your insights!

Comment: I think its available if you go to Terminal and type ```diskutil info diskIdentifier``` or you can go to Disk Utility, select the disk, and click on "Info" in the top right corner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either `diskutil info ...` or `sudo newfs_exfat -N ...` to get various (but different) details of your ExFAT file system:

1. Get the device list:

   ```
   diskutil list
   ```
2. Choose the partition:

   ```
   diskutil info diskXsY
   ```

   Example:

   ```
   user@host ~ % diskutil info disk1s2
      Device Identifier:         disk1s2
      Device Node:               /dev/disk1s2
      Whole:                     No
      Part of Whole:             disk1

      Volume Name:               Share
      Mounted:                   Yes
      Mount Point:               /Volumes/Share

      Partition Type:            Microsoft Basic Data
      File System Personality:   ExFAT
      Type (Bundle):             exfat
      Name (User Visible):       ExFAT

      OS Can Be Installed:       No
      Media Type:                Generic
      Protocol:                  PCI
      SMART Status:              Not Supported
      Volume UUID:               B44618D6-7DA7-35B0-BB27-C39785AA75F8
      Disk / Partition UUID:     7C734251-4E83-4537-885C-237D94F50633
      Partition Offset:          210763776 Bytes (411648 512-Byte-Device-Blocks)

      Disk Size:                 1.1 TB (1073530011648 Bytes) (exactly 2096738304 512-Byte-Units)
      Device Block Size:         512 Bytes

      Volume Total Space:        1.1 TB (1073495408640 Bytes) (exactly 2096670720 512-Byte-Units)
      Volume Used Space:         10.0 MB (9961472 Bytes) (exactly 19456 512-Byte-Units) (0.0%)
      Volume Free Space:         1.1 TB (1073485447168 Bytes) (exactly 2096651264 512-Byte-Units) (100.0%)
      Allocation Block Size:     131072 Bytes

      Read-Only Media:           No
      Read-Only Volume:          No

      Device Location:           Internal
      Removable Media:           Fixed

      Solid State:               Yes
      Hardware AES Support:      No
   ```
3. or `sudo newfs_exfat -N diskXsY`

   Example:

   ```
   user@host ~ % sudo newfs_exfat -N disk1s2
   Reformatting existing ExFAT volume
   Partition offset : 411648 sectors (210763776 bytes)
   Volume size      : 2096738304 sectors (1073530011648 bytes)
   Bytes per sector : 512
   Bytes per cluster: 131072
   FAT offset       : 2048 sectors (1048576 bytes)
   # FAT sectors    : 65536
   Number of FATs   : 1
   Cluster offset   : 67584 sectors (34603008 bytes)
   # Clusters       : 8190120
   Volume Serial #  : 5ea31cc5
   Bitmap start     : 2
   Bitmap file size : 1023765
   Upcase start     : 10
   Upcase file size : 5836
   Root start       : 11
   ```

   Hint: the message "*Reformatting existing ExFAT volume*" is misleading; the file system won't be altered.
      From `man newfs_exfat`:

   ```
   -N      Don't create a file system: just print out parameters.
   ```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!  Related (from manpage):  ```If the -R option is not given, and the device is already formatted as ExFAT, it will preserve the partition offset, bytes per cluster, FAT offset and size, number of FATs, offset to start of clusters, number of clusters, volume serial number, and volume name (label).```